# Bitwise manipulation of signed integers

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
int p= -6969317
int r=0xff & (p>>16);
```

what "r" will show and how?

Comment: The best way?  Run it and see.  You would already have an answer to the question that you've already waited two minutes for.

Comment: Remember to tag with "homework" when it is homework.

Comment: @duffymo: And here is the tool -> http://ideone.com

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should first *attempt* to answer it yourself. If you still cannot answer it yourself, you should demonstrate to us that you have *tried* to answer it by including everything you have tried and discovered (including what failed for you).

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak - I've never seen that site before. Super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see binary representation of your `int`, use:

```
public static String toBitString(final int data){
    final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(32);
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        s.append(data >> i & 1);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `Integer.toBinaryString(...)`

Comment: It has one drawback - it truncates leading zeros